# Name photos when uploading photos in the database " System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper "

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

when i upload pic in asp mvc 5 save in database , save it by this name

`System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper`

whats the problem ? how can i solve this ?

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase UserPhoto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.DateRegister = DateTime.Now;
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Name = model.Name, Family = model.Family,
                PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber, Gender = model.Gender, BirthDay = model.BirthDay, DateRegister = model.DateRegister,
                IsActive = false, UserPhoto = model.UserPhoto, Email = model.Email };

            if (UserPhoto != null)
            {
                UserPhoto = Request.Files[0];
                var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UserPhoto.FileName);
                if (ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png")
                {

                    string filename = model.PhoneNumber + ext;
                    UserPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/Image/" + filename));
                    model.UserPhoto = filename;
                }
            }

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

.

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserPhoto, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" name="UserPhoto" id="fileUpload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

/*******************************************************************************************/

Comment: There's nothing in your code to indicate why this is happening. I suggest debugging and setting a breakpoint where the filename is set.

Comment: in `if` condation every this is okay but when exit in `if` and go on `var result` image name  is change .

Comment: First, [edit] your question to include all relevant information. Second, as I mentioned, there's nothing *in the code you are showing* that would cause the filename to change. Thus, it must be in code you are not showing. Perhaps `UserManager.CreateAsync` is altering `user` in some way?

Comment: no , i show every code my friend

Comment: Then there's nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first set the filename, you are setting `model`. But when you are later creating the user, you are using `user`. You don't do anything with `model.UserPhoto`, other than return it as the view.